# 'Nishbaati' or 'Nishbawti'

Tags: jewish-books, grammar-dikduk, torah-reading, text, vayelech

In Vayelech, the Tikkun Simanim has a couple ambiguities in the notes.  In shishi a sentence ends with "נשבעתי".  The text shows a patach, but the notes indicate should be a kamatz (in MT)?  Is it a typo in the tikkun?  Also, in chamishi, the word "ולמדה" has a mapik-heh but the notes say the tradition is NO mapik-heh?  Anyone help me with this?  Thanks!

It's the two adjacent notes on 19 and 21.  See pic.

[image: Tikkun parshat Vayelech]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For ולמדה: that doesn't mean "it's not a mapik hei". It means "this word doesn't appear anywhere else with a mapik hei".  You'd be right in normal Hebrew, but mesorah language is it's own code.

For נשבעתי: the Keser, as quoted in the note, has a patach, so that's what I personally use.  You can see the Keser yourself at aleppocodex.org.  In this particular word, it's not 100% clear to me as a patach, but aside from simanim, מאורות נתן (available on hebrewbooks.org) also says it's a patach, so I defer to their judgment.

Comment: The word לית means literally "there isn't", but since these notes usually note parallel structures elsewhere, in context it means "there isn't [another]". So here it means "there isn't another ולמדה with a Mappik"

Comment: @DoubleAA Is it specific to that word? See a related format of the word in Devarim 31:32. That has the mapik heh. To me, the mapik heh seems grammatically correct in both places. So, I'm puzzled as to why there would be any place that **didn't** have it, as it doesn't agree with the dikduk.

Comment: @DanF unless there's a particular local reason to think otherwise, a note like that will refer to only the exact spelling under discussion.